# Docker: как правильно запустить контейнер с nginx и python?

Tags: python, nginx, docker

Пытаюсь развернуть у себя на локалке вот этот опенсорсный проект,
https://lifescience.opensource.epam.com/indigo/service/index.html

но уже третий день не могу разобраться с тем, как оно все должно запускаться. Там вроде информации не много, но может в этом и проблема.

В разделе Run from Docker Hub есть команда (почему-то разорванная там на абзацы)

```
docker run --restart=always -d -p 8002:8002 -e "INDIGO_UWSGI_RUN_PARAMETERS=--plugin python3 --py-autoreload=1" -e "PYTHONPATH=/srv/indigo-python" -e "PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1" --name=indigo_service epmlsop/indigo_service:latest /bin/sh -c "supervisord -n"
```

и она скачивает и запускает нужный образ, но по ссылкам http://localhost:8002/ или http://localhost:8002/v2/indigo/info ничего не грузится.

Видимо нужно еще настроить nginx из блока Installation на странице проекта? Или это касается только случая если я хочу самостоятельно собирать все и запускать из образа со страницы [Downloads](https://lifescience.opensource.epam.com/download/indigo.html)?

Но с ним тоже не могу понять что делать. В архиве лежат файлы только .whl? Для них нужно вручную собирать Docker-контейнер из nginx и python?